# What's better practice: objc_msgSendv or NSInvocation?

Tags: objective-c

So I'm working on something in obj-c (I'd rather not say what) where I need to be able to call arbitrary methods on arbitrary objects with arbitrary variables.  The first two are easy enough to do, but I am unsure how to do the variable arguments.  To be clear, this is **not** about a function/method receiving variable arguments, but about sending them.  I have found two ways to do this: objc_msgSendv (and its variants) in the objective-c runtime, and NSInvocation.  NSInvocation seems easier and more like it's the 'best practice', but objc_msgSendv sounds like it should be faster, and I need to do this many, many times over, with completely different messages each time.  Which one should I choose?  Is objc_msgSendv taboo for a good reason? (the docs say not to call the objc_msgsend functions.)

P.S. I know the types of all the arguments, and not all of them are id-s

Also, (not part of the main question,) there doesn't appear to be a way to message super from objc_msgSendv, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do that in NSInvocation either, so any help on that would be great too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`objc_msgSendv` is deprecated;  is unavailable entirely in 64 bit Mac OS X apps.  So, regardless, don't use it.

The real question is whether or not you know the argument set at compile time or not.   If so, use `objc_msgSend` (or appropriate variant).

If not, then you are going to have to use some mechanism to encode the arguments into a call compliant with the C ABI specific to your particular target architecture(s).  `NSInvocation` is the easiest means of doing so, but you are correct in that there is overhead.

You could drop down to `libffi` to gain a touch of efficiency, but there is still a huge amount of overhead building your own calls vs. letting the compiler compile a bit of code.

If you have a finite # of combinations of argument and return types, you could compile a bunch of trampoline functions and use those.

Actually, the *real* question is "What are you trying to do?"   What you describe is fairly atypical.  Not that you might likely not have a very good reason, just that whatever it is is very interesting (to me, anyway)!

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea obj_msgSendv was depreciated.  What I'm doing is slightly contrived, but basically I'm a little peeved that I can't code on iPad.  So what I'm looking at doing is some way to write an interpreter for a subset of obj-c, so I'm not technically violating any of Apple's restrictions, even though I'm not releasing on the app store.  I'm only even considering this because objective-c runtime is so dynamic (eg. I can call through to cocoa/uikit with only strings and such).  Oh, and I never signed up for the SDK so I can't be under NDA ;)

Comment: Ahh... OK.  Then, ffi isn't available on the iPhone platform.  The iPad is under NDA;  can't discuss that here.

Sounds like a fun project.  I wish you luck.  You might want to have a look at F-Script Anywhere, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Beware premature optimization. I would start with the higher-level functionality (NSInvocation) because it will be easier to unit test, code, and debug. Then take measurements. Move to lower-level functionality (objc_msgSendv) only if your measurements show a significant amount of time spent in and around the NSInvocations (such as preparing them). Otherwise, even if objc_msgSendv is faster, you will receive no observable benefit, at the cost of code that is harder to maintain.